# find date gap in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

i have a table with userIds and some dates like this : -

```
    | userId |       dates        |
    | 1      | 2021-06-20 00:00:00|
    | 1      | 2021-06-24 00:00:00|
    | 2      | 2021-06-25 00:00:00|
    | 2      | 2021-06-28 00:00:00|
    | 2      | 2021-06-30 00:00:00|
    | 3      | 2021-06-22 00:00:00|
    | 3      | 2021-06-24 00:00:00|
    | 3      | 2021-06-27 00:00:00|
```

I want to find first date for every user with userId that doesn't exist:-

expected output: -

```
    | userId |       dates        |
    | 1      | 2021-06-21 00:00:00|
    | 2      | 2021-06-26 00:00:00|
    | 3      | 2021-06-23 00:00:00|
```

I'm using postgres, can someone help as the data is pretty large, 4m+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simplest method is `lead()` and aggregation:

```
select userid,
       min(date) + interval '1 day'
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by userid order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_date is null or next_date <> date + interval '1 day'
group by userid;
```

Or using `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (userid) userid, date + interval '1 day'
from (select t.*,
             lead(date) over (partition by userid order by date) as next_date
      from t
     ) t
where next_date is null or next_date <> date + interval '1 day'
order by userid, date;
```

You can also write the `where` clause as:

```
where next_date is distinct from date + interval '1 day'
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f8aaf17cbb7f4fe18ca6cbbe6d7f4aaf) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```
select DISTINCT ON (userId) userId, dates from table_name order by dates
```

Comment: . . This only returns dates in the table.  The OP is asking for dates that are *not* in the table.